# How can I split the Vim window vertically, and make the bottom panel some height?

Tags: vim, terminal, split, vi

With the [N]sp option, I can split a Window and make the Top panel of size N. Is there any way to make the bottom panel of some size?

Comment: I think you mean split horizontally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of ways:

- Use `:below <N>sp` to make a window beneath the current one of size `N` lines.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to switch to an existing window. Then `:resize N` to set it to `N` lines high.

Comment: You can also type Ctrl + W, a number, then plus or minus to change the primary dimension of the current window by that many lines.

Answer (score 3):

```
:below 3sp
```

splits and makes the bottom panel of size 3.